# Android: Cannot call SortedSet methods in Google Guava's ImmutableSortedSet

Tags: android, guava

The Android compiler complains that Google Guava v12's `ImmutableSortedSet` doesn't have the methods, `first()`, `last()`, etc., and that `ImmutableSortedSet` doesn't implement `SortedSet`. I am currently using Android API 8. Here's some sample code:

```
/* 
 * I only have one set, 'mSet', but for the sake of this example
 * I added an ImmutableSortedSet instance.
 */
private final SortedSet<Item> mSet;
private final ImmutableSortedSet<Item> mImmutableSet;

private MyObject(Collection <? extends Item> items) {
  // Fails -- cannot convert from ImmutableSortedSet<Item> to SortedSet<Item>
  mSet = ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(items);
  mImmutableSet = ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(items);
}

private Item getFirstItem() {
  // Fails -- no such method 'first()' in ImmutableSortedSet
  return mImmutableSet.first();
}
```

**UPDATE**
I did a bit of digging, and it turns out `NavigableSet`, the interface that `ImmutableSortedSet` implements, only became available in API level 9 and up. I am unfortunately constrained to using API level 8. My question still stands though. Is there a way to fix this without having to play with Google's code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava 12.0 does not support your version of Android, so please stick to version 11.0.2 for now until we have a backport.